# How to pass project to a task?

Tags: sbt

I'm writing a `Task` that needs access to the `Project` - it needs to iterate through the `dependencies` to do some side-effect specific to our build. I need to be able to work out transitive internal and external dependencies (i.e. modules and jars) of children modules of `thisProject`.

I'm currently doing something like this to pass the other things that I need (`name` and Ivy-managed deps via `libraryDependencies`):

```
myTask := runMyTask(
  (name in Compile).value,
  (libraryDependencies in Compile).value
)
```

I still need another parameter like

```
(project in Compile)
```

but such a key does not exist.

How am I supposed to get the Project?

NB I realise this is probably not possible - without an evil hack involving named lookup of projects from a manually maintained hashmap - because of the Project/Task/Phase axis, but worth asking anyway in case there is a clean solution.

Comment: Why do you need a project instance if all you need is `libraryDependencies in Compile in thisProject` (*aka* `{.}/compile:libraryDependencies`)?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I need to be able to work out transitive internal and external dependencies (i.e. modules and jars) of children modules of `thisProject`.

Comment: Ah, but that's what `update` task offers. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Update-Report.html. Do you need more? When the project in which `update` is called has aggregates or project dependencies they will get included, too. What else would you need?

Comment: cool! The real information is hidden in the obscurely named `configurations` field. Please add this as the answer and I will accept it :-) If you have more sbt foo to dispense, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144580

Answer (score 1):

Use `thisProject` or any other `lazy val` that you've defined in the build.

```
> help thisProject
Provides the current project for the referencing scope.
> inspect thisProject
[info] Setting: sbt.ResolvedProject = Project(id runtime-assembly, base: C:\dev\sandbox\runtime-assembly, configurations: List(compile, runtime, test, provided, optional), plugins: List(<none>), autoPlugins: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin))
[info] Description:
[info]  Provides the current project for the referencing scope.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/C:/dev/sandbox/runtime-assembly/}runtime-assembly/*:thisProject
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Load) Load.scala:210
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:ivyConfigurations
[info]  *:name
[info]  *:organization
[info]  *:cacheDirectory
[info]  *:baseDirectory
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:thisProject
[info]  {.}/*:thisProject
[info]  */*:thisProject
```

Give it a try in `consoleProject` as follows:

```
> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
import sbt._
import Keys._
import dsl._
import _root_.org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin._
import _root_.de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin._
import _root_.com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin._
import _root_.sbtassembly.Plugin._
import _root_.sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.CorePlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
import currentState._
import extracted._
import cpHelpers._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> thisProject
res0: sbt.SettingKey[sbt.ResolvedProject] = sbt.SettingKey$$anon$4@1f3eff94

scala> thisProject.eval
res1: sbt.ResolvedProject = Project(id runtime-assembly, base: C:\dev\sandbox\runtime-assembly, configurations: List(compile, runtime, test, provided, optional), plugins: List(<none>), autoPlugins: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin))

scala> thisProject.eval.dependencies
res2: Seq[sbt.ClasspathDep[sbt.ProjectRef]] = List()
```

There's also `configurations` field that holds a list of available configurations for the project. Use it if you need to query for the value of a setting, say `libraryDependencies`, across configurations.

```
scala> thisProject.eval.configurations
res3: Seq[sbt.Configuration] = List(compile, runtime, test, provided, optional)
```

You may also want to read about ScopeFilter in [Getting values from multiple scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Getting+values+from+multiple+scopes) *"that gets values from multiple scopes"*. Including a sample from the page:

```
lazy val core = project

lazy val util = project

lazy val root = project.settings(
   sources := {
      val filter = ScopeFilter(inProjects(core, util), inConfigurations(Compile))
      // each sources definition is of type Seq[File],
      //   giving us a Seq[Seq[File]] that we then flatten to Seq[File]
      val allSources: Seq[Seq[File]] = sources.all(filter).value
      allSources.flatten
   }
)
```

Comment: that's a very verbose way of saying `thisProject in Compile` which returns [ResolvedProject](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.ResolvedProject) ;-) Where is the list of tags that are available for each of the phases?

Comment: sorry, I was a little hasty in accepting this as an answer. Unfortunately, `ResolvedProject` does not allow me to obtain resolved versions of its dependencies: I need to be able to descend the project dependency tree.

Comment: Can you show the code where my understanding failed? It'd be so much easier with a *working* example that would need some parts filled in to have a complete solution. Doable?

Comment: You're right with `dependencies` being of no interest here. I was lured by the name :(

Comment: yeah, I really do need `Project`, not `ResolvedProject` (or some other version of `Project` that lets me ask questions such as "what are my dependencies"). If you know how to resolve a `ProjectRef` to a `ResolvedProject` that would be of benefit.

Comment: w00t! To answer my own comment: `Project.getProjectForReference(project.dependencies(0).project, struct).get`

Comment: Please share your solution so we all can learn from your experience! Thanks.

Comment: I haven't been able to get a reference to the `Project` so this is not an answer