# How to add a dependency on the update stage in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I am writing an sbt task which needs to do some work before any compilation takes place (e.g. in the `update` phase).

If I were adding a dependency before the compile for a specific project, I'd do this:

```
project settings (
  compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn myTask
)
```

and if I wanted to do this before `update` I'd do

```
project settings (
  update <<= (update in Compile) dependsOn myTask
)
```

but how do I do this for **after** `update` but before any `compile`?

Comment: Have you tried `ThisBuild` scope instead of `Compile` scope? I guess `(compile in ThisBuild) dependsOn myTask` will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you override update in Compile, something like (update in Compile) := { (update in Compile).value; your task }

Comment: @MustafaSimav That gives me `Reference to undefined setting: {.}/*:compile from {.}/*:compile`

Comment: @monkjack tried that, it doesn't return the correct type

Comment: Well no, cos you need to return it. Let me do a proper answer.

Comment: See my proper answer, if its wrong post up a comment and I'll nuke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(update in Compile) := {
  ((update in Compile) andFinally {
    myTask.value
  }).value
}
```

Comment: aah, you want me to actually run my task there instead of referencing it's key. This works but it does limit somewhat what I can depend on, e.g. `dependencyClasspath` is not available. However, luckily I am able to perform task with `UpdateReport` as the input.

Comment: You can reference anything you need in that. So you can do dependencyClasspath.value, or you could do that in your task for example.